# Sleep longer the night after workout

Tags: sleep

I like to swim laps as it is not only healthy, but a sort of meditation.  Most days, I will swim a mile or so late (because that's when the pool is open).  I noticed that as I do this every day, I tend to need more sleep.  Normally, I sleep around 7-7.5 hours but after working out like this every day for 3-4+ days, it seems like I need 8-9 to just function.  Is this normal?  I thought working out was supposed to give you energy.  Also, I do have mild insomnia (part of the reason I started swimming in the first place).

Note: I realize there are simillar posts, like [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11999/proper-sleeping-time-after-tough-workouts), but I haven't found one specific to this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal to need more sleep.

If you were swimming 20-30 minutes yes you will feel energised, but if you are swimming for an hour it's pretty normal to feel tired and need more sleep.

Maybe you should mix things up a bit.  Some days a shorter swim, some days longer.

I'm sure there are some swimmers out there.  That could suggest some interval sessions.  But depending in your goal, I would just mix the distances up a bit. Ie hard easy days, to help you recover, and for you to feel more energised on the shorter recovery days

Comment: Thank you!  I will start swimming less on days where I want to feel energized and more on days where I want to get a solid workout.  I didn't realize that's how it worked.  Very helpful, thanks again!

Comment: No problem.  Hard easy day pattern is the norm for most endurance sports.  It's also important to listen to your body, so if you intend to do a long session, and you get to half way and it just seems so much harder than normal, don't be frightened to cut the session.  Your body will thank you for it the next time you swim.